# Next js CPU consuming 100% cpu on production when deploying doker and nginx

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, cpu-usage

i got stuck at one place with next js
and not able to find the solution ,So the problem is that we deployed our next js application with nginx without any custom server but after 10 to 20 minutes on production the cpu spikes upto 100% and not come back untill we restart the container this is happening on normal traffic . there are only two pages that got maximum traffic one is in both of these pages i am using get server side props for getting data server side.
let me know if you can suggest any optimization fix or something if  i am mising with the next js prod deplyoment

on vercel its not giving the issue want to achive same thing on nginx with pm2 or docker.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code is confidential so i cant share it here but i can share the execution :-

in my page first i am calling an api in getServerSideProps function that run on server side and return some props now i am using this props in my page its self which is normal in next js .